# game center leaderboard integration with cocos2d game

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

i set up 3 leader boards for my cocos2d game. when i click on the leader board button, the first page is one of the leader boards. and i have to tap back button to view all the leader boards and choose another. 
here is my code

```
- (void)leaderboard {
    CCLOG(@"show leadboard");
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController) {
        leaderboardController.category = [[GameCenterComponent sharedGameCenter] leaderboardCategory];

        leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        [delegate.viewController presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

and after commenting out leaderboardController.category line. it still starts with one of the leader boards. so is there a way to start out with the leader boards list page?

Comment: also is there a way to change the position of 'Welcome Back XXX' Banner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is [by design](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW9):

> The category property allows you to configure which category screen is
>   displayed when the leaderboard opens. If you do not set this property,
>   the leaderboard opens to the default category you configured in iTunes
>   Connect.

You can change which leaderboard is the default leaderboard in iTunes Connect.

To answer your other question: no, you can't modify the "Welcome back" banner in any way.

Comment: hey, thanks man. i learn game center from your book ^_^ thank you so much.